# Identify and save Spotify links in specific channel with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to program a Discord bot that scans a channel in a guild for Spotify links, then saves them to a file which I can then beam to my webserver. Ideally the latest links posted would be on top, and descending down.

What I'm having trouble with is finding and saving the links. I've seen some methods of detecting URLs with regex, although those seem to be for deleting invite links and wouldn't work for my purposes.

Is this possible to do with discord.py?

Comment: Can you provide some samples of the kinds of urls you want to detect?  A regex approach is probably possible with something like `https://[[^/]+\.]+spotify.com\..+`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Here are some examples:

https://open.spotify.com/album/20r762YmB5HeofjMCiPMLv?si=2WzgNVn9QByQk0liJehxog

https://open.spotify.com/album/7D2NdGvBHIavgLhmcwhluK?si=8zAz_gOoTLCKhMOs92yuOA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the whole channel using [`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.TextChannel.history) and use regex or something similar to find the links and save them in a list:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import re

client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

def saveToFile(links):
    with open ("Output.txt", "a") as f:
        for link in links:
            f.write(link + "\n")

@client.command()
async def getLinks(ctx):
    links = []
    channel = client.get_channel(1234567890)
    async for message in channel.history():
        if "https://open.spotify.com/" in message.content:
            message = message.content
            message = re.search("((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)", message).group(0)
            links.append(message)
    saveToFile(links)

client.run(your_bot_token)
```

The regex will work for any link, you can adapt it to only work for Spotify links if you prefer.